Could an exomoon be bombarded by electromagnetic radiation from its parent gas giant and still be habitable enough for life to evolve?
What I'm trying to accomplish here is having a setting where complex electronics are not feasible or so difficult to shield that they're not worth the time. Mechanical technology is the rule on this planet. There will be humans, but any effects of EM radiation can be handwaved away. I'm more interested in native life adapting to it.

Earth is bombarded by one point four kilowatts per square meter of electromagnetic radiation from the sun, and life did very well here. (1.4 kW/m² is about 5.5 megawatts per acre or 13.8 megawatts per hectare.) No gas giant comes even with 0.01 percent of the intensity of electromagnetic radiation put out by a star. Yes, visible light and infrared rays and ultraviolet rays are electromagnetic radiation.

Given we don't understand abiogenesis, at all, any answer comes down to sure, maybe.

The gas giant orbits a blue giant with constant Carrington Events
To understand "constant Carrington events" we need to start with the Carrington event.

The Carrington Event was the most intense geomagnetic storm in recorded history, peaking on 1–2 September 1859 during solar cycle 10. It created strong auroral displays that were reported globally and caused sparking and even fires in multiple telegraph stations. The geomagnetic storm was most likely the result of a coronal mass ejection (CME) from the Sun colliding with Earth's magnetosphere.

Solar storms can and do wreak havoc with electronics. While the Earth hasn't experienced anything like the original 1859 event since that event, we have experienced some nasty solar storms.
So it's really not the gas giant that's the problem — it's your star. The gas giant actually serves to moderate the problem. As the moon passes behind it, it's shielded from the chaos of the star. But the moon's orbit only need be fast enough that it's not worth trying to use otherwise stored and protected electronics during that "night" cycle.
From the perspective of disbelief, it's really, really, really, really, really hard to justify the lack of electronics in an advanced society. Things like Carrington events, EMP, even lightning strikes, affect objects with long wires. The long writes are mandatory because you need enough length to couple enough energy from the event to damage the electronics connected to the wire. The shorter the wire (e.g., the metal in microchips), the less susceptible it is to any such events.
However, only physicists and electrical engineers would know that and we're willing to suspend our disbelief for a good story.
Yeah, but I really wanted radiation!
Hard radiation causes grief in a different way. Where something like lightning or a Carrington event will couple energy onto a wire, causing a surge in electricity that (easily) physically damages what the wires are connected to. Hard radiation doesn't do that at all. It knocks electrons around like pool balls!

Environments with high levels of ionizing radiation create special design challenges. A single charged particle can knock thousands of electrons loose, causing electronic noise and signal spikes. In the case of digital circuits, this can cause results which are inaccurate or unintelligible. This is a particularly serious problem in the design of satellites, spacecraft, future quantum computers, military aircraft, nuclear power stations, and nuclear weapons. In order to ensure the proper operation of such systems, manufacturers of integrated circuits and sensors intended for the military or aerospace markets employ various methods of radiation hardening. (Source)

If it's strong enough, this can cause enough disruption to upset the voltage in the substrate of microchips. This is similar to what a Carrington event or an EMP does to long wires, but it takes so much radiation to actually damage the chip that everybody's dead and it doesn't matter if it's damaged. However, changing that voltage does upset the operation of the chip. It seriously upsets the operation. Check this out:

The short-time high-intensity pulse of radiation, typically occurring during a nuclear explosion. The high radiation flux creates photocurrents in the entire body of the semiconductor, causing transistors to randomly open, changing logical states of flip-flops and memory cells. Permanent damage may occur if the duration of the pulse is too long, or if the pulse causes junction damage or a latchup. Latchups are commonly caused by the X-rays and gamma radiation flash of a nuclear explosion. Crystal oscillators may stop oscillating for the duration of the flash due to prompt photoconductivity induced in quartz.

The problem with using radiation as the rationalization for your non-electronics society is that (simplistically) if you have the technology to build radiation-sensitive device, you have the technology to harden it. And you can always harden it to the point where if the hardening is insufficient, then (as I said earlier) everybody's dead anyway and it no longer matters.
In fact, if humans colonized this moon, then they had radiation-hardened electronics just to get there and, one would think, they'd be bright enough to appropriately harden devices expected to work there. Which is a long way of saying I believe this solution less than I believe a chaotic star.
Yeah, but why would anybody colonize a star system with a chaotic star?
The cool thing about stars is that they age. In other words, the star wasn't always chaotic! When the expedition was planned, it was perfectly normal. When the expedition arrived at the moon, the star was perfectly normal.
And then it entered a previously unknown "cycle" — one that cycles every hundred-thousand years or so. So long that it's reasonable for the humans to not realize what they were getting into. And then one day everyone was saying, "oooh! Look at the pretty aurora borealis!"
And then it was, "Um... why are the aurora happening on the equator?"
And then it was "Uh... Larry? Why can I see aurora on the equator of the gas giant?"
And then it was, "dang nabit, my calculator stopped working..."
And then all hell broke loose.
You sure your way is better?
Nope. Carrington events, lightning, EMP... you can protect all electronic equipment from the damage these things cause with a well-designed Faraday cage. I'm grateful for the science-fiction tag because in the Real World those events are only a problem because everybody and their dog are unprepared for them. But in your environment they'd be prepared. It is therefore unrealistic to have an advanced space-faring society without electronics.
But in a science-fiction world all we need is the rationalization for why your world is the way it is — and then you simply ignore everyone who might complain and write a good story, laughing all the way to the bank while the whiners and haters are stuck playing Lotto and wasting time on Facebook.
And if you want proof that it can be done, check out Johnny Worthen's Coronam series.
